# Comparing series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Can anyone explain why if I compare the coefficient of $x^{n}$ of the equation
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a(n)x^n= \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x}{1-x^3}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^5}-\frac{x^3}{1-x^7}+...$$
I can get
$$a(n)=k_{1}(4n+1)-k_{3}(4n+1)$$ where $k_{i}(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$ that are congruent to $j$ modulo $4$?

Comment: no it is like that

Comment: Q-series with Applications to Combinatorics, Number Theory, and Physics:  page 126

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{1-x^{2m+1}} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{m+2mk+k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
where $a_n$ is the number of non-negative integer solutions $(m,n)$ to $m+2mk+k = n$, i.e., $$4mk+2m+2k+1 = 2n+1 \implies (2m+1)(2k+1) = 2n+1$$
Hence, the coefficient $a_n$ is the number of divisors of $2n+1$.

Comment: How do we go from divisors of $2n+1$ to divisors of $4n+1$?

Comment: @Elaqqad I believe $2n+1$ has **no** even divisors...

Comment: @Theo The claim in the question is incorrect. For instance, the coefficient of $x^7$ is $a_7=4$, since it occurs in the expansion of the first term $\dfrac1{1-x}$, second term $\dfrac{x}{1-x^3}$ third term $\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^5}$ and eighth term $\dfrac{x^7}{1-x^{15}}$. However, $k_1(4\cdot 7 +1) - k_3(4\cdot 7 +1) = 2 \neq 4$.

Comment: @Elaqqad $2n+1$ is odd and hence has **no** even divisor. All divisors of $2n+1$ are odd. Hence, each product $ab=2n+1$, provides a valid $m$ and $k$.

Comment: @Elaqqad I agree that the claim is incorrect, I just wanted to tease a bit about the odd divisors reference ;) Hope you didn't take it too personally

Comment: @Elaqqad It reads only as divisors of $2n+1$.

Comment: This is indeed the answer to the original question. I answered the modified alternating question.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{1-x^{2n+1}}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{n+(2n+1)k}\\
\end{align}
$$

> The coefficient of $x^m$ is the the number of factors of $2m+1=(2n+1)(2k+1)$ that are $1$ mod $4$ ($n$ even) minus the number that are $3$ mod $4$ ($n$ odd). This confirms the formula in the question.

---

Each prime factor, $p$, of $2m+1$ that is $3$ mod $4$, which has an exponent of $k$, contributes to this difference of factor counts, a factor of
$$
\overbrace{1-1+1-1+\cdots+(-1)^k}^{\text{$k+1$ terms}}
$$
which is $1$ if $k$ is even and $0$ if $k$ is odd.

Each prime factor, $p$, of $2m+1$ that is $1$ mod $4$, which has an exponent of $k$, contributes to this difference of factor counts, a factor of
$$
\overbrace{1+1+1+1+\cdots+1}^{\text{$k+1$ terms}}
$$
which is $k+1$.

> Thus, if we break $2m+1$ into $p_1$, the product of primes that are $1$ mod $4$, and $p_3$, the product of primes that are $3$ mod $4$, then the coefficient of $x^m$ is the number of factors of $p_1$ if $p_3$ is a square, and $0$ if $p_3$ is not a square.

Note that if $m$ is odd, then $2m+1\equiv3\pmod4$. This means that $2m+1$ has at least one prime factor that is $3$ mod $4$ to an odd power. Thus, the coefficient of $x^m$ is $0$ if $m$ is odd.

Here are the terms up to $x^{50}$:
$$
1 + 2 x^2 + x^4 + 2 x^6 + 2 x^8 + 3 x^{12} + 2 x^{14} + 2 x^{18} + 2 x^{20} + 2 x^{22} + x^{24}\\ + 2 x^{26} + 2 x^{30} + 4 x^{32} + 2 x^{36} + x^{40} + 4 x^{42} + 2 x^{44} + 2 x^{48} + 2 x^{50}
$$

Comment: Ah, I see that the question was changed. This answers the modified version, which is correct.